# Samba share stopped working for me a few weeks ago

Tags: server, samba

A few weeks ago I believe there was some updates to samba on my 14.04 server.  Ever since then, when trying to connect from my windows machines I can get to the point of seeing the folders, but when I try to access any of them I get a permissions error.  Here is my setup:

```
[MediaServer]
path = /
available = yes
force users = root
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

This machine isn't connected to the internet unless I specifically allow it to be, so years ago when I set these settings I thought I was allowing all machines on my network to have access.  Has something changed or is there something else that could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which turned out to be caused by [a known bug in Samba](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11647). It looks like this will be fixed in future versions.

In the meantime, the short-term workaround is:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/root
sudo mount -o rbind / /mnt/root
```

Then add the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
/    /mnt/root    none    rbind    0    0
```

Then, edit your smb.conf file to use "path = /mnt/root" instead of "path = /".